# How to fix: GUI application who control a simple command of ffmpeg with python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, pyqt5

I want to make a graphic application with only 2 buttons (start / stop) that allows to launch a subprocess (start) and stop it (stop).
(I'm using Python3, PyQt5 and ffmpeg)
The process captures the screen in a video and save it to an mp4 using the ffmpeg command to launch the POpen command.
To make a clean output of the command, ffmpeg uses 'q' that I write by  stdin.

In a simple script it works for me but I can't get it to work within the buttons.

My knowledge is very basic and as much as I look for information I do not understand what I am doing wrong, I appreciate any comments that let me move on.

This is my code:

```
import sys
import subprocess
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton

class Ventana(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Button 1
        pybutton = QPushButton('REC', self)
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethodB1)
        pybutton.resize(50, 32)
        pybutton.move(50, 50)

        # BOTON 2
        pybutton = QPushButton('STOP', self)
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethodB2)
        pybutton.resize(100, 32)
        pybutton.move(150, 50)


        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('FFMPEG')
        self.move(800, 400)
        self.show()

    def clickMethodB1(self):
        global ffmpeg
        filename_mp4 = 'c://tmp//output.mp4'
        print('REC')

        command = 'ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" '+ filename_mp4

        ffmpeg = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,                                                    encoding='utf-8', shell=True)


    def clickMethodB2(self):

        print('STOP')
        ffmpeg.stdin.write(str('q'))            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ventana()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Note: The start button launches the process but does not stop with the stop button, but the instruction does work in a simple code

Comment: Okay keep in mind that python-pyqt only works on one process within a single process no matter what -- so you launch your sub-process and it starts and while you can click the button out here in this process it does not do anything within the sub-process because it is tied up doing something already --- to do this you would probably have to implement your own sub-process and use the multiprocess.event() as this would allow you to code your stop method to turn the event() off which if done correctly stops the subprocess so that it can receive commands

Comment: Oh note your button click probably does send an event to the sub-process but it is to busy to look at the event queue

Comment: @maoca Saying *In a simple script it works for me but I can't get it to work within the buttons.* Doesn't help at all, explain yourself better

Comment: I want to say that in a estruturated code without control with buttons, the code works fine.